How to alleviate RuntimeWarning: Unexpected end-group tag: Not all data was converted
I'm executing Notebooks on AWS and recently some of them started coming back with:
/emr/notebook-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightstep/http_connection.py:45: RuntimeWarning: Unexpected end-group tag: Not all data was converted 
resp.ParseFromString(r.content)

I have noticed several other answers that seem to be related to dependencies, but nothing specific to lightstep. I'm getting this error in a number of different cells in the Notebook, usually when I'm fetching data for a number of IDs.
I have tried replicating the error locally by creating a virtual environment with python 3.7 to match the error above, but I can't replicate it.
Any ideas on how to alleviate this error?
